# Why does Android Studio think my API level is 1 in static analysis?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I am running Intellij's static analysis in Android Studio and I am getting a `Calling new methods on older versions` error. For some reason, it says that my current min api is 1, and that the needed is 11. Here is the relevant part of my `build.gradle`:

```
int minSdk = hasProperty('minSdk') ? property('minSdk').toInteger() : 15
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 23
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax for minSdk?

Comment: Just so that everyone knows, there is a problem apparently, but it isn't with the syntax. the property `'minSdk'` does exist, I just don't know where. Anyone have any ideas where that could be configured locally? (I have no `settings.groovy` file and `local.properties` only contains `sdkDir`.

Comment: `settings.gradle`*